# Issue with SQL Non-negatives and TinyInt

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table

So in this assignment I was given the specific instruction:

"Add a new driver_age column to the drivers table with a TINYINT(2) data type that must not be a negative value and can’t be null."

So I put the following code into the system:

```
`ALTER TABLE EPDriver.drivers ADD driver_age TINYINT(2) NOT NULL;`
```

I keep getting an error from the system saying:

> [Error]: Task 2. Expected: Add a new driver_age column to the drivers
>   table with the specified data type. Try again.

This is done in Codio which auto-grades my code. I think it has something to do with TINYINT being able to go negative but now I don't know how to correct that parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `UNSIGNED` attribute to the [`TINYINT(2)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) so that it can never be negative.

```
ALTER TABLE EPDriver.drivers ADD driver_age TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```